# Solrj - setRequestHandler("/suggest");

Tags: java, solrj

I am trying to get back suggestions using SolrJ and I get back a casting error;

> `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map`

The response from the server is;

> `{responseHeader={status=0,QTime=16},suggest={
>      fuzzySuggester={but={numFound=0,suggestions=[]}},
>      infixSuggester={but={numFound=10,suggestions=[
>         {term=Squash, winter, <b>but</b>ternut, cooked, baked, without salt,weight=11155,payload=}, 
>         {term=Squash, winter, <b>but</b>ternut, cooked, baked, with salt,weight=11155,payload=}, 
>         {term=Squash, winter, <b>but</b>ternut, raw,weight=10630,payload=},
>         {term=Margarine-like spread, SMART BALANCE Light <b>But</b>tery Spread,weight=5161,payload=}, 
>         {term=Squash, winter, <b>but</b>ternut, frozen, unprepared,weight=4790,payload=}, 
>         {term=Squash, winter, <b>but</b>ternut, cooked, baked, without salt,weight=4570,payload=}, 
>         {term=Squash, winter, <b>but</b>ternut, cooked, baked, with salt,weight=4570,payload=}, 
>         {term=Squash, winter, <b>but</b>ternut, raw,weight=4226,payload=}, {term=Peanut <b>but</b>ter, smooth, vitamin and mineral fortified,weight=3907,payload=}, 
>         {term=Peanut <b>but</b>ter, chunky, vitamin and mineral fortified,weight=3907,payload=}]}}}}`

This is the code that goes with it;

> ```
>       SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("but");
>       query.setRequestHandler("/suggest");
>       query.setParam("wt", "json");
>
>       QueryRequest qryReq = new QueryRequest(query); 
>       QueryResponse resp = qryReq.process(solrClient);
>
>       SuggesterResponse suggesterResponse = resp.getSuggesterResponse();
>
>       Map<String, List<String>> suggestedTerms = >suggesterResponse.getSuggestedTerms();
>       List<String> suggestions = suggestedTerms.get("mySuggester");
> ```

I am not sure why this is happening is any light on this would be great.

Comment: Please show the full code, in the body itself, not just the 1 line you think is most relevant in the title.

Comment: Could you please also post how is configured in your `solrconfig.xml` the request handler `suggest` ?

Comment: Could you please also post the version of SolrJ and the version of your Solr Server?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. have you got a solution for this issue?

Comment: similar question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55115760/solrj-org-apache-solr-common-util-simpleorderedmap-cannot-be-cast-to-java-util