# solrj "org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map" exception when using "/suggest" handler

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I get the class cast exception when trying to run the solrj program using /suggest handler. I am able to get the suggestion response from Solr Admin UI, but when the same is being tried from solrj client the above exception arises.

The solr-config.xml entries are as follows :

```
 <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
            <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
            <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
            <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
            <str name="field">suggestfield</str>
            <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>

    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="suggest">true</str>
            <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
        <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
            <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

The schema.xml contains the field

```
<field name="suggestfield" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

which is a copyField of multiple fields.

The java code is as follows :

```
 String url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/testwidget"; 
    HttpSolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(url).build();
    client.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());

    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setRequestHandler("/suggest");
    query.setParam("suggest.build", true);
    query.setParam("suggest", true);
    query.setParam("suggest.dictionary", "mySuggester");
    query.setParam("suggest.q", "acc");

    QueryResponse response = client.query(query);
  System.out.println(response.getSuggesterResponse().getSuggestedTerms());
```

The exception is as follows :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse.setResponse(QueryResponse.java:161)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:942)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.query(SolrClient.java:957)
    at com.intellectdesign.canvas.solr.SolrjTest.main(SolrjTest.java:41)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it set `XMLResponseParser` and then request `wt=json`. I think https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/solrj/src/test/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/TestSuggesterResponse.java may be used as a sample for beginning.

Comment: Yeah that was by mistake.."request wt=json" was used for some other purpose. Still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Does it make any sense to use a multivalued field for a suggester? Which one does it suggest? The copyField directive will put multiple chunks of text in a single field.

What result do you want? This design doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The reason for making it a copyField is to get suggestions from not a single field but many fields. Since its a suggestion field, the suggestions are needed from various fields not just one. As given in the official doc https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/suggester.html " To be used as the basis for a suggestion, the field must be stored. You may want to use copyField rules to create a special 'suggest' field comprised of terms from other fields in documents." the suggest field could be a copyField.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue "org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap cannot be cast to java.util.Map" is below snippet of code.

```
if ( "suggest".equals( n ) )  {
        _suggestInfo = (Map<String,NamedList<Object>>) res.getVal( i );
        extractSuggesterInfo(_suggestInfo);
      }
```

The class which performs this operation is "QueryResponse" under package"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response" which is in-built inside solrj.

In my case i performed the suggest operation using Rest Client.

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/{core}/suggest?q={term}";
Map<Map<?, ?>, Map<?, ?>> forNow = restTemplate.getForObject(url, HashMap.class);
```